# React Native Expo: When running on Phone via QR code the application looks different from debugging in Chrome

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, expo, native

When I run my React Native application with Expo on Chrome it looks fine. But when I try to debug it with the QR code on my android and iphone all the boxes and placements are off. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, it would be nice to see some of your code, in order to determine what the problem is. Remember to be specific and informative. Now that being said, this sounds to me like a problem of positioning, do you use a lot of absolute positioning when placing objects on the screen?

Remember that as you test your app on different screens, the screen sizes and aspect ratios will change, and your components might move around if they are are not relatively positioned with flexbox.

But please provide some more information, and the relevant code in order for us to properly evaluate and consider your problem. :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).